# Why does the branch cut for the principal branch of log(z+1) start at z=-1?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, branch-cuts, branch-points

If I cut away the negative real axis to make log(z+1) single-valued, why does the branch cut start at z=-1 and not at the origin z=0?

Why does the shift in argument from log(z) to log(z+1) make it ... single-valued on the real interval (-1,0)?

Thanks,

Comment: Where is (the real) square root $\sqrt{x+1}$ defined? Certainly for some negative numbers.

Comment: Hi @mrf, but if I naively cut away all of the negative axis, then circling around, say, -.5, also makes the function jump by an argument of 2pi there, too, making the function multivalued there, and -.5 would also be considered a branch point of the square root (with argument x+1). Where am I going wrong with this thinking?  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In general if a cut $C$ makes $f$ single valued, then
$C-\{s\} = \{c-s| c \in C\}$ will make $z \mapsto f(z+s)$ single valued.

This is because $z+s \notin C$ **iff** $z \notin  C-\{s\}$.